# How do I highlight a word or a phrase in a command's output?

Tags: command-line

For example i enter `lshw` for listing hardware modules; when I hit enter, it gives me a long list of output, but what if I want to highlight one word or phrase in the output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell) StackOverflow question, you can use `grep -E --color`

For example if you want to highlight the word "product" you can do this :

```bsh
lshw | grep -E --color 'product|'
```

To highlight the word "product" with output in less you can do this :

```bsh
lshw | grep -E --color=always 'product|' | less -R
```

Comment: Found it !
For example I want to color width I use this command
lshw | egrep width
But it collapse the output of -lshw command what if I want to see the output of -lshw command while width is highlighted ?

Comment: To see all output of a command where the output is too high you need to use less and for keep color in less you need to add the option -R .

Comment: @YaserMowwlavezada I add the command in the answer. For you're case if you want to highlight the word "width" use this command :

Comment: @YaserMowwlavezada lshw | egrep --color=always 'width|' | less -R

Comment: Notice that [`egrep` is deprecated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html), `grep -E` would be better. Also worth to be pointed out that the keyword (`product` in this case) is interpreted as a pattern, so if the keyword contains special characters (`*`, `+`, `{`, `}`, ...) those will need to be escaped.

Comment: how can i color multiple regex using grep? for example i want to color 2 different words with 2 different colors and i dont want to use ansi escape codes.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ANSI escape sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html) , one can colorize anything in console. Combining that method with awk, we can filter specific words , and make them colorized.

Consider this example:

```
$> df | awk  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/sda/) $i=sprintf("\033[0;36m %s \033[0;00m",$i)}; print}'
```

[image]